# How to process files in groups of three

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting, find, uniq

I have a folder with backup files out of 3 months and younger than 1 year. They have the same part of names but other part is date of backups (so I have group of files). From all of files in my folder, I need to keep only 3 zip files from each group: not the last 3 modified files from all files, but last 3 files from each of the groups, because backups could be created in a different time in the past. Other files, delete.

Example:

List of zip files:

```
ais_2016-02-21.zip
ais_hg_2016-07-31.zip
ais_hg_2016-08-07.zip
ais_hg_2016-08-14.zip
ais_hg_2016-08-21.zip
ais_hg_2016-08-28.zip
ais_hg_2016-09-04.zip
asf_2016-07-17.zip
asf_2016-07-24.zip
asf_2016-07-31.zip
asf_2016-08-07.zip
asf_2016-08-14.zip
asf_2016-08-21.zip
asf_2016-08-28.zip
asf_2016-09-04.zip
asf-ant-tasks_2015-12-13.zip
asf-ant-tasks_2015-12-27.zip
asf-ant-tasks_2016-01-17.zip
asf-ant-tasks_2016-01-31.zip
asf-ant-tasks_2016-02-14.zip
asf-ant-tasks_hg_2016-02-28.zip
asf-ant-tasks_hg_2016-08-07.zip
asf-ant-tasks_hg_2016-08-14.zip
asf-ant-tasks_hg_2016-08-21.zip
asf-ant-tasks_hg_2016-08-28.zip
```

Groups:

```
ais
ais_hg
asf
asf-ant-tasks
asf-ant-tasks_hg
```

And I need to keep 3 last modified files from `ais`, 3 from `ais_hg`, 3 from `asf`, etc. However, there are more groups of files (130) so I can't write manually each of the groups in the script.

So here I am. I have two arrays, and I don't know where to go from here.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=(/media/sf/zipp/outOFtime/*.zip)
cuts=($(find ${files[@]} -type f | sed 's/.{15}$//' | sed 's/^.{1}//' | sort |uniq ))

for f in "${cuts[@]}" 
do
    echo -e $f 
done
```

Comment: Remove external image-links and provide textual representation of the same.

Comment: In my opinion you should consider a different language for this, such as Python or Ruby.

Comment: but this is impossible unfortunatly :( i have to use this language because this is my task in my new work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the list of unique groups. (I'm assuming that no file has a newline in its name.)

```
for f in *.zip; do
  echo "${f%%_*}"
done | sort -u > groups.txt
```

Next, get the list of files matching each group, and output only the last three:

```
while IFS= read -r group; do
  files=( "$group"_*.zip )
  for f in "${files[@]:0:${#files[@]}-3}"; do
    rm "$f"
  done
done < groups.txt
```

---

First, `"${var:s:l}"` expands to a substring of length `l` starting at position `s` of the value of `var`. When applied to an array, it expands a sequence of `l` array elements, starting with the element at index `s`. So here, if there are 9 elements in `files`, then `${#files[@]}` expands to 9. Subtracting 3 from this leaves 6 (both `s` and `l` are evaluated in arithmetic contexts), so we have an intermediate expression of `${files[@]:0:6}`. The result, then, is the first 6 files in the array.

Comment: brilliant, it works, but I have yet to test it...; could you explain me how this line of loop does work ? "${files[@]:0:${#files[@]}-3}";